# Install from ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg4 403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Tags: 64-bit, ffmpeg, opencv

I am (linux beginner) trying to install `Opencv` on Ubuntu `bionic 18.04`, 
following this git [shell scripts to install different version of OpenCV](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV) instructions.

But I'm getting a `403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]` when I run :

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

it return :

```
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libcv-dev
  libcvaux-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtkglext1 libhighgui-dev libilmbase-dev
  libjasper-dev libjasper1 libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-calib3d2.4v5
  libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-core-dev
  libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-dev libopencv-features2d-dev
  libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-flann2.4v5
  libopencv-gpu-dev libopencv-gpu2.4v5 libopencv-highgui-dev
  libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-imgproc2.4v5
  libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml-dev
  libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-nonfree2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect-dev
  libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-ocl-dev libopencv-ocl2.4v5
  libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-photo2.4v5 libopencv-stitching-dev
  libopencv-stitching2.4v5 libopencv-superres-dev
  libopencv-superres2.4v5 libopencv-ts-dev libopencv-ts2.4v5
  libopencv-video-dev libopencv-video2.4v5 libopencv-videostab-dev
  libopencv-videostab2.4v5 libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni
  libopenexr-dev libpangox-1.0-0 libswresample-dev libswscale-dev
  libxml2-utils opencv-data
0 upgraded, 58 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,286 kB/23.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 122 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libavutil-dev amd64 7:4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libswresample-dev amd64 7:4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libavcodec-dev amd64 7:4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libavformat-dev amd64 7:4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libswscale-dev amd64 7:4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavutil-dev_4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch
...
```

I tried to visit the links with a proxy, same error, they just seem to be broken.

Is there any alternative, or a way around this problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you mean the links worked for you, and if so, haw can I have access to those URLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg4` has been removed.

See https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-4

> This PPA has been removed from public access as part of a protest
>   against the abuse of open-source projects by large companies. For more
>   detail visit the main page here: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and I understand the author's complains, but what I'm I suppose to do now. is there any way around ?

Comment: You can ask the author.

Comment: I'm gonna open an issue on the "shell scripts installation" git repo, I guess I'm not the only one concerned by this problem.
Thanks again for your kindness.